# ODE $y''-(1+y')^2=0$ how to solve?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Find solution
>   $$y''-(1+y')^2=0$$

I tried to get $y''-y^{'2}-2y'-1=0$ but then I don't know what to do. Should I use substitution earlier?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With substitution $y'=u$, the $\text{DE}$
$$y''-(1+y')^2=0$$
is
$$u'-(1+u)^2=0$$
or
$$\int \dfrac{du}{(1+u)^2}=\int dx$$
and then
$$y'=-1-\dfrac{1}{x+C}$$
Now solve this!

---

**Edit:**

The equations of the form
$$y^\prime+p(x)y=q(x)y^2+r(x)\tag{1}$$
named [Riccati equation‎](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccati_equation), I must note that Riccati solved the equation ‎$$y^\prime+by^2=cx^m\tag{2}$$
at first time and $(1)$ solved later by Bernoulli. $(1)$ with $r=0$ known as Bernoulli equation. In general $(1)$ can be solve if one of it's special solution $y_p$ be known.